# How to decrypt DB2 data in another data warehouse platform

Tags: algorithm, encryption, db2

We need to send data from db2 (db2 for AS400) to another data warehouse platform (Hive). But we need to encrypt data in DB2 first. And then target server will connect to DB2 to export data and decrypt data in target server.

SQL to encrypt data in DB2:

```
INSERT INTO TESTAES
SELECT ENCRYPT_AES( ACCOUNT, '1234567890') FROM TESTPLAIN;
```

I know the DECRYPT_CHAR function in DB2:

```
SELECT DECRYPT_CHAR( ACCOUNT, '1234567890') FROM TESTAES
```

But after we load this table to another platform, we don't know how to decrypt the data. We don't know the DB2 decryption algorithm.

The way I thinks may works:

(1) Get the decryption algorithm of ENCRYPT_AES in DB2 and we can write a program in targer server to decrypt the data. But IBM shared this in any documents. I searched it in IBM DB2 document, just told us

> Encryption algorithm: The internal encryption algorithm used is from the CLiC Toolkit from IBM Research. The 128-bit encryption key is derived from the password using a SHA1 message digest?https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscaencryptaes.htm

(2) Get the decryption algorithm package of ENCRYPT_AES in DB2 and we can import this package in targer server to decrypt the data. Did IBM have such package?

(3) Use another open-source/common function/package to encrypt data in DB2. And we know the algorithm and we can write program/or use the same algorithm package to decrypt the data. But I don't how can we encrypt data in AS400 db2 except ENCRYPT_AES. Maybe write a java program or something else?

Would anyone share this experience in encrypted data migration to another platform.

Answer (score 0):

it is standard AES algorithm, but the default CCSID in AS400 is EBCDIC.

do you need to convert DATA to UTF-8 after decryption.

Comment: I know ENCRYPT_AES is standard algorithm. But I tried and did not decrypt the data outside DB2. Because there are 4 modes (ECB/CBC/...) for AES. And there are 4-5 padding methods. How db2 SHA1 key. It's too much unkown. So I don't know how decrypt the data outside DB2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question can be closed. Becuase

(1) I asked IBM Technical Support, he suggest us to write encryption/decryption function by ourselves. Maybe the algorithm of DB2 encryption function is a secret.

(2) I created an DB2 UDF to call Java Program in AS400. Finally, it works. I can encrypt data in DB2 and after other database get encrypted data and it can be decrypted in other database.